# Adding search function for gem mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails, and I found this gem mailboxer for sending messages between the website users.  I am unable to write the search functions for `inbox` and `sent`.

**conversations controller**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end

  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body,recipients:[])
  end

   def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to implement these?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the gem you are talking about. However, in general, you could do something like this in Rails.

Assuming you have a model Message, with `name` as a column, you could do this:

```
Message.where("name like ?", params[:name])
```

where `params[:name]` could be either "inbox" or "sent".